# How to fix rails api testing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I am new to creating an API with Rails and am trying to create a test.

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "/api/v1/iosapps", :type => :api do


    context "view all apps" do
        let(:url) { "/api/v1/iosapps" }
        it "json" do
            get "#{url}.json"
            iosapps_json = Iosapp.all.to_json
            last_response.body.should eql(iosapps_json)
            last_response.status.should eql(200)
            iosapps = JSON.parse(last_response.body)

            iosapps.any? do |p|
                p["name"] == iosapp.name
            end.should be_true
        end
    end

end
```

I get an error saying the below.  Any advice on how to fix this?

```
Failure/Error: get "#{url}.json"
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   Could not find table 'iosapps'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test db is not ready. You need to run

```
rake db:migrate
rake db:test:prepare
```